# Why in jpaRepository is used Long?

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm new with Spring boot and JpaRepository. I was wondering why the use of Long instead of another data type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use `Long`, you can use any type like `String`, `UUID` or a custom type.

E.g. all these are possible:

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long>

public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, String>

public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, UUID>

public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, UserId>
```

The important bit is that it refers to whatever you use as primary key for your entity.